# In Android, how can I keep verticalSpacing always equal to the horizontalSpacing in GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have declared GirdView in xml layout as shown below.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/movies_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:columnWidth="92dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I intend to show fixed size images(vertical rectangle not square) in this `GridView.` I have set the `columnWidth` to `auto_fit` so that horizontal space can be used optimally by the `GridView.` as per the available screen size.
I have set the `stretchMode` to `spacingWidthUniform` so that columns will be placed at equal distance from all sides.

I want to set the `verticalSpacing` equal to the `horizontalSpacing`. I can't do it in xml here because at runtime the `horizontalSpacing` will depend on the space available on the screen. Also, when device orientation is changed, the `horizontalSpacing` will change.

My questions are:

1. How can I make sure that `verticalSpacing` will always be equal to the `horizontalSpacing`?
2. How can make the `GridView` start layouting its first column from the beginning plus padding and end layouting last column to the end of `GridView` minus padding?

**EDIT 1**

I tried @simas solution to use the mentioned custom grid view.
For that,

1. I copied this class to my source directory.
2. Included this grid view in layout xml as shown below.

```
<com.aviras.ashish.popularmoviesapp.widgets.CustomGridView
    android:id="@+id/movies_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_item_width"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    tools:listitem="@layout/grid_item_movie_poster" />
```

3. Set the adapter to this gridview as shown below

   ```
   CustomGridView moviesGridView = (CustomGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies_gridview);
   moviesGridView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(rootView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), mMovies));
   ```

It still shows the different spacing for the columns and rows as shown below.
[image]

**EDIT 2**

@simas in the second question by 'start layouting' I mean that the `GridView` should start drawing the first column at the start of the `GridView` and last column of the `GridView` should end at the end of the `GridView`. Also, the columns and rows should have the equal spacing.
Let me know if that clarifies my question some more.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom GridView class and modify the functionality of `setHorizontalSpacing` and `setVerticalSpacing` like this:

```
public class CustomGridView extends GridView {

    public CustomGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHorizontalSpacing(int horizontalSpacing) {
        super.setHorizontalSpacing(horizontalSpacing);
        // Call parent class to set the vertical spacing to be equal to the horizontal spacing
        super.setVerticalSpacing(horizontalSpacing);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVerticalSpacing(int verticalSpacing) {
        // Prevent the derived class from modifying the vertical spacing
        /*super.setVerticalSpacing(verticalSpacing);*/
    }

}
```

Then use the custom class in xml like this:

As for your second question: I couldn't really understand what you meant by "start layouting".

An image example of your desired result would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custome gridview woth textview and put the space like you want and also set it horizontally or vertiaclly easily.

Comment: What height and width should I set  to the <code>TextView</code> so that both <code>horizontalSpacing</code> and <code>verticalSpacing</code> in <code>GridView</code> are equal?

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:columnWidth="80dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:splitMotionEvents="true"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />




and  textview that is :

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#55d3d3d3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="asdfasdadasds"
        android:textColor="#77FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: This did not work for me. My problem is to keep the horizontalSpacing == verticalSpacing. The solution you have adds the vertical spacing which can also be added with verticalSpacing attribute. The problem I wish to solve is to satisfy condition horizontalSpacing == verticalSpacing in any case on all screen sizes.\